# Taskpane Word Add-Ins (office-js) - The Search function return empty object {} in Word 365 online

Tags: reactjs, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

I have created a Taskpane Word Add-Ins, written in React Typescript.
This sideload add-in is going to search a list of words in Word document and replace them by new words. All functionality works well in desktop MS Word and find all the words. When I upload manifest to Word 365 online, Taskpane loads and looks find but when I click on button to search, then nothing find. The result of search function is always empty object {}
Below you can see my code for searching part that will trigger when user click on search button. It is working on desktop version but is not working in Word 365 online

```
(async () => {
        try {
          let options = Word.SearchOptions.newObject(context);
          options.matchCase = false;
          options.matchWholeWord = true;
          options.ignorePunct = true;
          
          await Promise.all(
            WordList.map(async (data: customWord) => {

            // NOTE: In Word 365 online, searchResults is always {} 
              const searchResults = textSelected
                ? context.document.getSelection().search(data.word, options)
                : context.document.body.search(data.word, options);

              searchResults.load("items, text");
              allSearchResults.push(searchResults);
            })
          );
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
    })();
```

Does anyone know why search result is empty in Word Online? Is it related to code Promise.all() when running via browser?

Comment: Thanks for raising this question. we can't repro locally. In order to better assist you, could you give us the steps to stabilize the repro? And the files/codes required by repro if possible.

Comment: Hi @Jinghui-MSFT. This is a private repo in GitHub. I am not sure how I can give to private access? Seems having an email will let me to add you as contributor

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out where the issue comes from. This issue occurs when having matchWholeWord option in your search function or al least set it to True. By removing this option I was able to see the result in Word online eventhough the result I got wasn't as I expected which is make sense. I didn't try for other search options and don't know for others and these are only three of in my case. Below is my change to get result in Word online.

```
let options = Word.SearchOptions.newObject(context);
options.matchCase = false;
options.ignorePunct = true;
```

This is a [SearchOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/search-option-guidance) bug in Word online which is reported as an issue in office-js GitHub repo.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/218

Microsoft common! Fix it! We need it!